# How to get current state of HEAD in git?

Tags: git

For example, if I'm on a branch, I want to get the branch name. But if I'm in detached HEAD state, I want to get the commit id.

Basically, I'm looking for an interface to `.git/HEAD` file. I know I could just `cat` it, but maybe there's a command that will do that for me (so that I won't have to handle edge cases like `GIT_DIR` not being inside `GIT_WORK_TREE` etc.)

Comment: Just call `git status` you will get a output like `HEAD detached at <sha-commitid>`

Comment: That's some idea, but this solution is not very script-friendly, as I would have to parse the output of `git status`. Ideally, I would like a command that would just output the branch/committish which I would later feed to `git checkout` to restore previous repo state.

Comment: `git branch | grep -e "^*" | awk '{print $NF}'` is the name of current branch. If empty, `git rev-parse HEAD` or `git log -1 --pretty=%H` returns the commit sha1 value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using git completion https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash. Which is usually automatically installed.

You could call

```
echo $(__git_ps1 '%s')
```

Otherwise use.

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null || git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: I've just realized that if there are multiple branches pointing to the same commit, `git symbolic-ref` may return the wrong one (i.e. not the one that is checked out). Any ideas how to improve it?

Comment: @JanWarchoł I suggest using completion script, which provides `__git_ps1`, it will solve number of problems for you.